# Meteor: how to accept user input in a set of form fields

Tags: forms, meteor

New to Meteor.  I have a form with several fields

```
<template name="addcityform">
  <form name="addcity">
    <input name="city" class="city" type="text">
    <input name="population" class="population" type="text">
    <input type="Submit" value="Add City">
  </form>
</template>
```

I just want to insert the fields into the database, but I'm stumped on how to do it.  Here's what I currently have after several attempts:

```
Template.addcityform.events({
  'submit .addcity' : function(evt, template) {
    Cities.insert({
      city: template.find('input.city').value,
      population: template.find('input.population').value
    });
  }
});

// this gives: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

I saw some examples that use `Session.set` and `document.getElementById`, but that seems clumsy to me due to the potential for namespace conflicts.  I'd like to do this the 'right way' so that it's extensible later, for example, I could put multiple instances of the form onto the page and they should be independent of each other.  What is the 'right way' to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You lack an event.preventDefault() in the "submit form" handler, or else the page will reload and ruin the single-page app experience of Meteor.

I would do something like :

```
<template name="addcityform">
    <form>
        <input name="city" class="city" type="text">
        <input name="population" class="population" type="text">
        <button type="submit">Add City</button>
    </form>
</template>

Template.addcityform.events({
    "submit form": function(event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Cities.insert({
            city: template.find(".city").value,
            population: template.find(".population").value
        });
    }
});
```

What's cool about Meteor templates is that css selectors used within them are local to the current template, meaning that "submit form" will always refer to "submit event of the form element in enclosing template", given that you only have one form in the template.
The same applies to template instances .find method : it will return an element matching the css selector within the template or its sub-templates.
This allows you to have multiple instances of your addcityform that will be independent from each other.